# Fetching files with Even minutes from aws using boto3 and python3 on local machine?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have some CSV files over the AWS s3 bucket where the file format is Year_Month_Date_Hour_Minute.csv

I have to fetch those files on my local machine which contains even minutes in it's name

I have already tried it using the for loop but It is calling the

```
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket, Prefix=prefix)
```

30 times for each hour, which takes a lot of time to return the output
refer the below piece of code to see what I have already done and share the best approach we can implement here

```
paginator = self.s3.get_paginator('list_objects')
            files = set()
            for i in range(0, 60, 2):
                pages = []
                prefix = '{:%Y_%m_%d_%H_}'.format(self.date) + '{}'.format(i)
                pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket, Prefix=prefix)
                items = []
                for page in pages:
                    if page.get('Contents') == None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        for item in page['Contents']:
                            items = set([item['Key']])
                            files = files.union(items)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an unusual requirement. If your sole/primary query is for files with an even number of minutes in their key then either store them under a higher-level prefix of `even/` or `odd/` or consider indexing them by even/odd minutes in a database (e.g. DynamoDB). Probably the latter.

Comment: Why not list all of the files for an hour with one list, and only pull down the ones that end with an even number?